# Template not loaded in Generic Formview used in Mezzanine project

Tags: django, mezzanine, django-generic-views

I want to add a contact form in my homepage in a mezzanine project. Homepage inherits from Page class and is loaded perfectly using the mezzanine project.

I created a new generic view in my project and I bound urls.py to it.

```
class Home(FormView):
   template_name = "index.html"
   form_class = ContactForm
   success_url = '/'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       page = Page.objects.get(title='Home')
       return {
           'page': page,
           'params': kwargs,
       }
```

If if load the page in a terminal, using django.test.client, I found exactly what I want in my homepage which is in page.homepage.

But the template `index.html` is not loaded at all. I only get the `base.html`. So variables based on `{{ page }}` are not found. `index.html` seems to be ignored.

Could you help me to find out what's going wrong there? How, for example, can I test the template index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the template wasn't load. The one returned was `index.html` from mezzanine site-packages which is out of my understanding. So I give up the solution of rewriting a special view for my homepage.

Instead, the easiest way to rewrite a view using Mezzanine is using the page_processor. Then everything works fine. There is a solution here which explains it:

[page processors with mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-processors)